# STM32F3 Interrupt-driven ADC Callback

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I've been trying to learn through the STM32F3Discovery board how to use the ADC with interrupt-driven callback to move ADC data into a user-defined variable.

I have followed two sources to build my code. The Visual-GDB tutorial located [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/).

As well as the generic CubeMX setup for my device with the HAL library.

Here are relevant functions to my program:

**System Clock Initialization**

```c
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC12|RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC34;
  PeriphClkInit.Adc12ClockSelection = RCC_ADC12PLLCLK_DIV1;
  PeriphClkInit.Adc34ClockSelection = RCC_ADC34PLLCLK_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}
```

**ADC Initialization**

```c
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode;
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;

  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_601CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;

  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

**IRQ handling, callback & main program loop**

```c
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* AdcHandle)
{
    adcVal1 = HAL_ADC_GetValue(AdcHandle);
}

void ADC_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc1);
}

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();

  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1); // REF1
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn); // REF2
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_2_IRQn, 0, 0);
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

My expectation is that my ADC should be set up in regular, constant conversion mode. Lines marked with REF1 and REF2 should enable end of conversion interrupts, which my `ADC_IRQHandler` and `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback` should subsequently be invoked, storing my `hadc1->Instance->DR` register value in variable `adcVal1`.

When debugging, the `hadc1->Instance->DR` register will update as expected, reading the correct voltage values that I set on the ADC channel. So I know that the ADC read is functioning correctly. When setting a breakpoint in my callback function, the function is never called, and so I can conclude there is an error in my logic in initiating or handling the ADC IRQ, so `adcVal1` is always 0.

Can anyone provide correct setup of IRQ handling for my device, or point out my error?

Comment: What is the resulting sample rate given your clock frequency and sample time setting?  In many cases the ADC sample rate will be too fast to reasonably handle using interrupts.  Using DMA might be a better solution, also for a single value conversion, you can simply read the value directly from the ADC register, handling the interrupt only really makes sense if you were to place multiple conversions in a buffer to be processed asynchronously - and then DMA is still a better solution.  You can then handle the much lower rate DMA interrupt on buffers of multiple samples.

Comment: You should certainly set the interrupt priority _before_ enabling the interrupt.

Comment: Go through the check list in step 16 of the tutorial, specifically whether the interrupt is pending in the NVIC.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Clifford. I'll keep it in mind going forward in my projects. I can't answer the sample rate, I'm not proficient in STM32 yet. I understand that DMA is my best option. The purpose of this specific usage was to get a better understanding of how interrupts are handled. I'm not trying to do anything specific right now, other than understand what my options are, and how to use them. :)

Comment: Yes; I looked at the tutorial, and it too makes the same point about DMA. 601.5 sample time is relatively long..

Comment: Regarding the sample rate, on STM32 ADCs, the time between samples is the sample time +12.5 cycles (614 cycles in this case).  Your sysclock is multiplied by the PLL from the 8MHz HSI, the PLL settings result in 64MHz.  The ADC is on the AHB3 and both the AHB and ADC prescalers are set to DIV1, so you have 64000000/614 sps, or approx 104.2ksps - that will be the interrupt rate  - one every 9.6 microseconds!  You will get jitter if it is preempted by a higher priority interrupt; it will not be suited to accurate signal processing, OK for "voltmeter" style  level measurement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IRQ handler name `ADC_IRQHandler` is correct for the STM32F407 used in the tutorial, which has a single ADC, but you are using a different part - the name differs, so your handler is not really a handler - just an unused function.  If you do not override the appropriate handler with a function of the same name, the default "do nothing" handler will be invoked.

The symbol naming convention for IRQ handlers is straightforward, IRQ `XXXXX_IRQn`, has a handler called `XXXXX_IRQHandler`, so for `ADC1_2_IRQn`, the handler is `ADC1_2_IRQHandler`

To be sure for your specific target, check the the interrupt handler weak symbols defined in the file normally named *startup_stm32f3xxx.s* (where the *xxx* part defines your specific target - [startup_stm32f303x8.s](https://github.com/PaxInstruments/STM32CubeF3/blob/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F3xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f303x8.s) for example).

Note that the header stm32sxxx.h ([stm32f303x8.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F3/TARGET_STM32F303x8/device/stm32f303x8.h) for example):

```
/* Aliases for __IRQn */
#define ADC1_IRQn           ADC1_2_IRQn
...

/* Aliases for __IRQHandler */
#define ADC1_IRQHandler           ADC1_2_IRQHandler
...
```

Using these aliases makes sense only if you are not using the other peripheral with interrupts, since you can only have one handler for both peripherals.

Comment: Interesting. Re-named my IRQHandler function to ADC1_2_IRQHandler and the callback function is behaving as expected. I'll be sure to check that I am using the invoked functions in future. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @user1350065 : Yes you need to be aware that IRQ mapping on a specific STM32 depends on the series and on the peripheral set and that varies across the STM32 range even within the same series.  You might expect that the HAL would hide such details from you, but it is not that abstract despite its name.  Here just as you had to change `ADC_IRQn` in the tutorial, you have to change the handler name.

Comment: Fixed the example link to the correct .s file.  Added note about available aliases.